# Filter and take out certain elements of a date

Tags: python, datetime

There is a list of dates

```
['2020-03-24 09:00:00', '2020-03-24 12:00:00', '2020-03-24 15:00:00', '2020-03-24 18:00:00', '2020-03-24 21:00:00', '2020-03-25 00:00:00', '2020-03-25 03:00:00', '2020-03-25 06:00:00', '2020-03-25 09:00:00', '2020-03-25 12:00:00', '2020-03-25 15:00:00', '2020-03-25 18:00:00', '2020-03-25 21:00:00']
```

There are two things i want to do:

- I want to pull out all the dates related to today (and tommorow), like i want all the `2020-3-24`s filtered out of the rest of the dates.

> ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes
>   (0,) and (40,)

I keep getting the error of shapes, because they are mismatched, how should i fix this?

```
date_times = []
for i in raw_date_times:
    date =  datetime.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').date()
    if date == today:
        date_times.append(i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option using regular expressions, `re`:

```
from datetime import datetime
import re

d =  datetime.now()
date_today = re.search("([0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2})", str(d)).group(0)
ll = ['2020-03-24 09:00:00', '2020-03-24 12:00:00', '2020-03-24 15:00:00', '2020-03-24 18:00:00', '2020-03-24 21:00:00', '2020-03-25 00:00:00', '2020-03-25 03:00:00', '2020-03-25 06:00:00', '2020-03-25 09:00:00', '2020-03-25 12:00:00', '2020-03-25 15:00:00', '2020-03-25 18:00:00', '2020-03-25 21:00:00']
desired_dates = [s for s in ll if date_today in s]
desired_times = [re.sub(date_today, '',
                        re.search("([0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2})", str(s)).group(0)) for s in desired_dates]
```

which gives the follwoing output:

```
['2020-03-24 09:00:00', '2020-03-24 12:00:00', '2020-03-24 15:00:00', '2020-03-24 18:00:00', '2020-03-24 21:00:00']
['09:00', '12:00', '15:00', '18:00', '21:00']
```

Comment: its faster and more compact however im currently looking at simplicity

Comment: @beepbeep-boop What makes you say its faster?

Comment: @RoadRunner It appeared that the `re` implementation is faster, calculating the execution time gives the following:
`re` - ~0.0003
`datetime` - ~0.003

Answer (score 2):

Took a stab and this is what I came up with...

```
import datetime

start = ['2020-03-24 09:00:00', '2020-03-24 12:00:00', '2020-03-24 15:00:00', '2020-03-24 18:00:00', '2020-03-24 21:00:00', '2020-03-25 00:00:00', '2020-03-25 03:00:00', '2020-03-25 06:00:00', '2020-03-25 09:00:00', '2020-03-25 12:00:00', '2020-03-25 15:00:00', '2020-03-25 18:00:00', '2020-03-25 21:00:00']

new = [datetime.datetime.strptime(item, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for item in start] #Setting up each DT object at the beginning makes it much easier later on...

final_times = [] #initiate a final list for the times you desire

for date in new:
    if date.date() == datetime.datetime.today().date(): #last .date() on today is needed to compare str vs str
        final_times.append(date.strftime('%H:%M')) #only add the hour:minute

print(final_times) #['09:00', '12:00', '15:00', '18:00', '21:00']
```

There is also this [link to datetime documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) that describes the way datetime objects are used in more depth